# Running Node.js functions in AWS EC2 on Schedule

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Im trying to achieve the ability to run Node.js code on an AWS EC2 instance on a scheduled interval. It is similar to how AWS Lambda works, but Lambda doesnt supply the amount of resources that I need. I have a working Node.js app already, I just need to get it running on EC2 (I think).

Im new to servers and EC2, so I'm lost on how to achieve this. I am able to setup and run an EC2 instance just fine, but running the code is a different deal. My thought is to host the Node.js app on an EC2 instance, but run a Lambda function on a schedule that invokes the application to start in EC2. I just dont know where to start to learn how to do this.

As always, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use Lambda to schedule the jobs. Linux servers already have a job scheduling service on them called Cron. Do some searches for "cron" or "crontab" to learn how to schedule jobs on Linux.

Comment: The whole point of lambda is to not have to spin up ec2 instances.

Comment: @OlegDulin the question is specifically asking how to run scheduled tasks on an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by triggering your Node.js Lambda with a CloudWatch event.  Create an event rule with the [`putRule`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putRule-property) API.  Then create a target with [`putTargets`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putTargets-property) with the target ARN set to your lambda's ARN.  For example:

```
var cloudwatchevents = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents();
cloudwatchevents.putRule({
    Name: 'my-rule', 
    ScheduleExpression: 'rate(1 hour)`
}, function(err, result) {
    cloudwatchevents.putTargets({
        Rule: result.RuleArn, 
        Targets: [ {
            Arn: myLambdaArn,
            Id: '1'
        } ]
    }, function(err, result) {
        ...
    });
});
```

This will trigger your lambda once every hour.